# Эти улики запутанны/запутаны

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Эти улики запутанны/запутаны.`

`Эти улики так запутанны/запутаны.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны варианты:

(1) *Эти улики **запутанны** (неясны), трудно сделать вывод.* Краткое прилагательное, две буквы ***НН***.

(2) *Эти улики **так запутаны**. Возможно, кто-то сделал это намеренно.*  Краткое причастие, одна буква ***Н***.

**Словари**

**Орфографический словарь**

**запутанный**; кр. ф. **прич**. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. **прил**. (сложный, неясный) -ан, -анна

**Большой толковый словарь**

**ЗАПУТАТЬ**, -аю, -аешь; запутанный; -тан, -а, -о; св. 1. что.  2. что. **Сделать неясным, трудным для понимания; усложнить**. З. какой-л. вопрос. З. сюжет рассказа. **З. следствие**. 3. кого. Разг. Сбить с толку, ввести в заблуждение. З. противника своими действиями. З. слушателей разноречивыми фактами.

**ЗАПУТАННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -тан, -а, -о. 1. Беспорядочно перевитый, переплетённый; спутанный. З-ые нитки. З-ые волосы. З. моток пряжи. 2. **Сложный, трудный для уяснения, понимания.** З-ая фраза. З-ые отношения. З-ое условие задачи. З-ые обстоятельства дела. З. вопрос. <Запутанно, нареч. Говорить долго и з. Запутанность, -и; ж. З. показаний. З. мыслей.

Answer (score 0):

***Эти улики запутанны.***

***Эти улики так запутанны.***

В полной форме две Н, поэтому и в краткой две. В прилагательном *запутанный* две Н, потому что оно образовано от глагола сов. вида. Хоть и образовано от глагола, но в вашем примере это именно прилагательное, потому что имеется в виду признак.